# How to set default kernel in GRUB without Grub Customizer?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

After the recent update I wasn't able to start my system (black screen). So I powered off the PC and turned it on again.

Saw the following grub menu:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
System setup
```

I selected "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and saw:

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-42-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-42 ... (recovery mode) ...
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-41-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-41 ... (recovery mode) ...
...
```

I selected `Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-41-generic` and the system started (previously with `Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-42-generic` selected it didn't)

As I didn't always want to select it manually I tried to set it as the default kernel in grub:
So I opened '/etc/default/grub' and changed:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=2
```

Then executed `$sudo update-grub` and restarted the system. But it still wanted to load the latest kernel.

I also tried it with `GRUB_DEFAULT=3` but the result was the same.

My grub is:

```
#grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.11
```

I also got some errors while installing grub customizer:

```
...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic-lts-wily:
 linux-signed-generic-lts-wily depends on linux-signed-image-generic-lts-wily (= 4.2.0.42.34); however:
  Package linux-signed-image-generic-lts-wily is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic-lts-wily (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up grub-customizer (5.0.6-0ubuntu1~ppa1t) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.2.0-42-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-wily
 linux-generic-lts-wily
 linux-signed-image-4.2.0-42-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic-lts-wily
 linux-signed-generic-lts-wily
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I'm not sure whether I should reboot or uninstall it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I installed the grub customizer and set:

```
default entry
   predefined [Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-41-generic]
```

After this I noticed that the following entry appeared in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-41-generic"
```

Then I uninstalled the grub customizer made sure the entry was still there ran sudo update-grub and rebooted. Now the right kernel is used.

It looks like there is a specific syntax `GRUB_DEFAULT="submenu>menu"`. Didn't know about that...